# Is there a way to have exact image width in different devices' screens in react js with CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, printing, html2canvas, thermal-printer

I have a receipt design created using react. In CSS, I used 80mm in width and 90mm in height since using mm is recommended for printing. I capture this component using html2canvas which outputs an image and convert it to base64string and send it to an API which is responsible for printing. I've notice that when printed in paper (80mm x 90mm) with thermal printer that has 203dpi, the image is not exactly 80mm and it became smaller. What could be the possible reason for this?

This web app is run in two devices which have screen resolutions of 1080 x 1920 and 1920 x 1200. Given by the info provided by [w3.org CSS](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html), mm unit is recommended for printing. However, in 1080 x 1920 device, the printing result of the image become smaller (lesser than 80mm of the paper width) but in 1920 x 1200, the printing result of the image become twice as big of the paper width.

Comment: Does html2canvas keep in mind those units? And does it respect the DPI you require to create the image? What is your images final output size? What ios its given DPI?